# correct way of computing inner product with numba

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numba

I am trying to compute the inner product of two large matrices. it seems `numpy` create  copy of matrices when trying to compute the dot product and it causes me some memory issues. After googling around I found `numba` package promising. However I can't make it work properly . Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
import time, contextlib



@contextlib.contextmanager
def timeit():
    t=time.time()
    yield
    print(time.time()-t,"sec")


def dot1(a,b):
    return np.dot(a,b)

@jit(nopython=True)
def dot2(a,b):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = b.shape[1]
    K = b.shape[0]
    c = np.zeros((n,m))
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(m):
            for k in range(K):
                c[i,j] += a[i,k]*b[k,j]

    return c



def main():
    a = np.random.random((200,1000))
    b = np.random.random((1000,400))

    with timeit():
        c1 = dot1(a,b)
    with timeit():
        c2 = dot2(a,b)
```

with following running time:

```
dot1:
(0.034691810607910156, 'sec')

dot2:
(0.9215810298919678, 'sec')
```

can anyone tells me what I am missing here?

Comment: It is likely that the matrix multiplication is already so much optimised (in C, or even FORTRAN) under the hood (probably using CPU cache/vector optimisations as well), that a just-in-time compilation will not be able to beat that.

Comment: I had a look at the memory requirements, but I don't see any any evidence of duplication of the matrics during the execution of `np.dot`. There could be some overhead (I haven't delved into it much), but certainly not twice the memory required.

Comment: @Evert please take look at `Linear Algebra on Large Arrays` section in http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformanceTips . it is mentioned there: `Although C is only 40 by 40, inspecting the memory usage during the operation of dot will indicate that a copy is being made. The reason is that the dot product uses underlying BLAS operations which depend on the matrices being stored in contiguous C order`

Comment: I don't know about numba. As for memory, have a look at [https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4062] and see if that's relevant. If you're "dot"-ting the transpose of a matrix with itself (I can confirm this issue), or using numpy < 1.8, there's a chance you run into memory issues.

Comment: @Evert I am not dotting with transposed of my matrix but with a matrix with transposed shape. I means `n by m` with `m by n` where `m` is roughly `80000`. the solution in the post with `np.rollaxis` seems interesting but I can't understand how it works and how should I apply it for my case. any input regarding that?

Comment: Create a new question about the memory problem, with an example that people can verify (i.e., create a self contained example that uses somewhere around .5 - 2 GB of memory, which most people can handle).; this question is was about numba and the (lack of) speed-up.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is the naive algorithm. BLAS implements a faster one.

Quoting wikipedia's [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) page:

> Nevertheless, it appears in several libraries, such as BLAS, where it is significantly more efficient for matrices with dimensions n > 100